# C++ Update Struct

Tags: c++, arrays, string, struct, assign

I have this:

```
typedef struct {
    char nome[50];
    char morada[100];
    char codpostal[8];
    char localidade[30];
    int telefone;
    int nContribuinte;
} CLIENTE;
CLIENTE c;
```

How do I update `c.nome` like `c.nome = "something";`? Can't figure out why wouldn't this work... `c` has already been filled with known info saved on a binary file

I'm supposed to do this: `if (Conf == 1) { scanf("%s", c.nome); } else { c = Clt.nome; }`

Comment: You don't need a `typedef` for `struct`s in c++, you could just name it.

Comment: Advice --- Stop writing `C` code.

Comment: In C++ arrays are non assignable, you can use a function to fill it out with your string literal, `strcpy` would work. Just make sure you've enough space for a nul terminator or some serious sadness will occur :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For C-like strings, use [strcpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/), like this:

```
strcpy(c.nome, "something");
```

The reason what you tried didn't work is that you used C-like strings, and not [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/), which is the C++ approach, and has overloaded the assignment operator. In that case your struct would look like this:

```
#include <string>

struct CLIENTE {
    std::string nome;
    ...
};
CLIENTE c;
c.nome = "something";
```

---

You can avoid the typedef, as described in [Difference between 'struct' and 'typedef struct' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c):

> In C++, all *struct declarations act like they are implicitly
>   typedef'ed*, as long as the name is not hidden by another declaration
>   with the same name.

Comment: why are you suggesting array of string `std::string nome[50]`. its should be `simply std::string nome`;

Comment: Leftovers @danishansari, but I could edit my post because it was in the review queue for a suggested edit! Thank you!

Comment: typedef is also not required in c++, since you are giving a c++ solution.

Comment: Oh now I understood what you meant, thank you @danishansari!

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks bud :D About the `typedef` thing. This is a school project, and the teacher want's students to use 20 years old code... `fseek`, `fread`, `fopen`, `fclose`, `printf `, you name it...

Comment: Well maybe he has a reason @C.Carrasquinho ;)

Comment: What about the int values? `strcpy` doesn't work for them (edit: Yes I will bud. Done :) )

Comment: @C.Carrasquinho `strcpy()` is for strings, it means string copy. For integers, just do `c. telefone = 5;`

Comment: that made me laugh for some reason xD Thanks again!